# Automatically run a program as root for GPIO?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, raspbian-wheezy, sudo, root

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian that I want to auto-login and then automatically run a program that uses the GPIO as root.

I have auto-login working as per [this website](http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html).

What is the best way to run a program that needs GPIO? Is it adding the `pi` user to sudoers permissions? Or would adding a line with sudo  to the bottom of the `~/.bashrc` file? I would guess the second so that the `pi` user can't do any other damage?

Comment: I personally add the command to `/etc/rc.local`. That way it runs on startup, regardless of whether autologon is enabled or not. (Commands in `/etc/rc.local` are always run as root, so no need to add `sudo`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run your program just add it to ~/.bashrc using sudo, as the pi user has sudoers permissions without password authentication already, this way the program will be started when you login.

What you can do instead to is create a service unit, is you are using arch on your pi just create a new systemd unit file in /etc/systemd/system and then enable it, the program will be started when the computer is powered on.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `sudo` in ~/.bashrc should work fine, on a standard Raspbian install the `pi` user has sudoer permissions already.

Alternatively if it is just a single program you wish to run, you can tell it to always run as root.

You do this by setting the owner to be root, then telling the file it is always loaded as if the owner of the file opened it.

Lets say I have a script called `test.sh` for example:

```
sudo chown root test.sh
sudo chmod +s test.sh
```

The first command makes the owner root, the second command tells it to load as the owner of the file.

If we now run the command normally it should run as the root user regardless of who started it or where (no `sudo` required).

Comment: Yes, adding a `sudo test.sh` in `.bashrc` worked. For some reason the second two commands didn't seem to, despite the programming running fine after changing to root with `sudo su` and also being listed as owned by `root` in `ls -l`.

Comment: What permissions did `ls -l` show (e.g. `-rw-r--r--`)?

Comment: It shows `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root pi`

Comment: The sticky bit is not set (the first symbol should be `s` not `-`), maybe I got the command wrong. I have changed the order and syntax to match a setup script I wrote ages ago for something else.

Comment: Still no luck with the new commands I'm afraid

Comment: **You cannot (effectively) setuid on a script.**  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/25985