# Start Service with Sudo

Tags: sudo, services

I am trying to run an Express API server with sudo permissions and have it automatically start on boot.

The API needs access to `bcm2835 library`, and I get the following when trying to run `node server.js`

> bcm2835_init: Unable to open /dev/mem: Permission denied
>   /home/pi/Documents/node_modules/rpio/lib/rpio.js:104
>   return bindfunc(optarg);
>
> Error: Could not initialize bcm2835 library
>   at bindcall (/home/pi/...) etc.

However it boots up fine running `sudo node server.js`.

I have created a service file at `/etc/systemd/system` as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Node API
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/pi/Documents/server.js
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=controller
User=root
Group=root
Environment=

TimeoutStopSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I found some guidance [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12853/automatically-run-a-program-as-root-for-gpio) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/806617/configuring-systemd-service-to-run-with-root-access), but they seem slightly off, since a sub-command needs sudo/root privileges.

**How can I run this service with proper permissions so it boots up with the Pi?**

I think the boot is failing silently in the background.

Comment: You probably need some environment variables for `node` to run and find the library.

Comment: Do you have an example? I'm not very familiar with environment variables, and I don't understand how a variable could be equivalent to running as sudo.

Comment: It's not related to`sudo`. Type `env` and see what might be used by `node`.

Comment: Type `env` where?

Comment: At a shell prompt.

Comment: OK. I see the variables. How will I know which one(s) are missing?

Comment: If you look at the error, it still seems like a permission setting to me...

Comment: The Unit is the right way but it has some needless options. You show us an error message. You say it is running with sudo so what is the command to reproduce this message? When starting the server with sudo, does it has some graphical output or only text? I don't know something about node server.js but is there a debug option, something like `node server.js -d` or so? Most server have such an option. If it has a debug option try it on the command line with sudo as before. Tell me if it works.

Comment: I don't think the service runs it as sudo. Service files are run from `/etc/systemd/system` on boot. `sudo node server.js` was an example of the script running manually without error.

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug a service because they start and stop silently in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/mem` must be run as root, so after a fresh install of Raspbian.

1. Create the service
2. Enable the service with `systemctl enable nameOfService`